# inserting values in to sql lite - java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have created a database and using the below code i am inserting the values in to the database. the code works fine.

the problem is since the code is in the onCreate method. every time i call the activity this will insert the data again and again.

i want this to insert the value only for the first time when i call the activity.

is there any way i can do it..thanks.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_db_result);

    Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 

    kovil insertData1 = new kovil("Murugan Kovil", "Murugan", "9.6680077",  
                                  "80.0147083", "image_name", "year_build", 
                                  "address", "city", "email", "website",
                                  "telephone1", "telephone2",  "Description");

    kovil insertData2 = new kovil("Murugan Kovil", "Murugan", "9.6661814",  
                                  "80.014883", "image_name2", "year_build2", 
                                  "address2", "city2", "email2", "website2", 
                                  "telephone12", "telephone22",  "Description2");

    kovil insertData3 = new kovil("Murugan Kovil", "Murugan", "9.6621890",  
                                  "80.0131851", "image_name3", "year_build3", 
                                  "address3", "city2", "email2", "website2", 
                                  "telephone12", "telephone22",  "Description2");

    ArrayList<kovil> arrayList = new ArrayList<kovil>();

    arrayList.add(insertData1); 
    arrayList.add(insertData2); 
    arrayList.add(insertData3);           

    for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
        dbhand.Add_Temple(arrayList.get(i));
    };
}
```

Comment: Use a query (a trivial **"SELECT Count(*) from MyTable"**) in your onCreate method to tell you if record count is 0. If so, proceed to insertion.

Comment: ya thank you that's a good idea. tnx.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo if you like you can write is as answer. i can give a tick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a query (a trivial **"SELECT Count(*) from MyTable"** will do) in your onCreate method to tell you if the record count is 0.

If so, proceed to insertion.

Answer (score 4):

Database setup such as populating the tables with default data is best put in your SQLite open helper `onCreate()`. It is only called once when the database is first created.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way you can execute a code only for the first time:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(prefs.getBoolean("FirstTime", false)) {
    //code that is to be executed every time

}else{
    // code to be executed only once the first time the app is run
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```